# Php time() value incorrect in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

On my website I want to store user's action as a timestamp in my database (so in a bigint type).

I use the php function time().

```
$date = time();
```

When I print `$date`, everything is fine.

But when I store `$date` in my database (mysql database),  I get an incredible value.

I just did it and the value i get is: `20180610051606` which represent the year `641468`!!!!

I don't understand what's wrong.

Update:

When I use int type to store the variable `$date` in the database the value that is stored is 4294967295

Here is my code:

```
$date = time();
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id,date) values(?, ?)");
$query->execute(array($id, $date));
```

Comment: why don't you use mysql time() datatype instead?

Comment: If you want to store a timestamp in a database, use a timestamp data type.

Comment: the timestamp data type or the time data type store only formatted dates (hour:minutes etc)

Comment: @user3783243 I edited my post (see update part)

Comment: use now() time format

Comment: @whoami `now()` is not a time format, it is a datetime.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the value: `20180610051606` that's stored in the db represents the current date.  `2018-06-10 05:16:06`

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth Yes, there is more to this question than is being presented. `time()` would never return that.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that `$datet` is not defined?

Comment: @user3783243 sorry i just made a mistake in my post. $datet = $date

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth Yes you are right i didin't notice it. But that's weird. When I print the value of $date it is the current timestap 1528607640. II don' understand what happen in the database

Comment: There must be more going on with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your column name as DateValue or something instead of date. and try the following code:

```
<?php
    require_once('init.php');
    $datetime = time();
    $con = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO TableName(Name, DateValue) VALUES('Bairavan', $datetime)");
    $con->execute();
?>
```